# Detect repeated keywords in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following data,

```
ID         Text            time
1          cri             2018-01-29 12:00:01
1          crim            2018-01-29 12:00:02
1          crimi           2018-01-29 12:00:03
1          crimin          2018-01-29 12:00:04
1          crimina         2018-01-29 12:00:05
1          criminal        2018-01-29 12:00:06
1          in              2018-01-29 13:00:01
1          ind             2018-01-29 13:00:02
1          indi            2018-01-29 13:00:03
1          india           2018-01-29 13:00:04
2          fu              2018-01-29 12:00:01
2          fun             2018-01-29 12:00:02
2          func            2018-01-29 12:00:03
2          funct           2018-01-29 12:00:04
2          functi          2018-01-29 12:00:05
2          functio         2018-01-29 12:00:06
2          function        2018-01-29 12:00:07
2          by              2018-01-29 13:00:02
2          bye             2018-01-29 13:00:03
```

I want to find out for an ID, within some time, whether we can identify cri,crim,crimi all are related to criminal and remove the remaining rows. I want to know if there is any way in python / Data science to detect this and remove it. I want output of this like,

```
ID         Text            time
1          criminal        2018-01-29 12:00:06
1          india           2018-01-29 13:00:04
2          function        2018-01-29 12:00:07
2          bye             2018-01-29 13:00:03
```

Can anybody suggest me ways to do this in python?

Comment: Try: [Python Filter](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html)

Comment: You have to design your own algorithm to judge the simlimar word, it does have some libs like [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches) already implement it, but may not meet your requirements.

Comment: Are criminal, bye, and function predefined or one has to learn?

Comment: @Tai has to be learned

Comment: @haimen I think maybe you split it into two questions. Learning them should be already challenging. Also, you should specify more clearly about how to learn them. Best.